# Accessing child XML elements with XPATH in Python

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xpath, xml-parsing

I'm parsing this XML file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i6hga7nvmcd6rxx/ct.cps?dl=0

From each `<Reaction>` tag I want its `name` attribute and the `name` attribute of its `<Constant>` children.

```
from lxml import etree

NSMAP = {"c": "http://www.copasi.org/static/schema"}

parsed = etree.parse('ct.cps')

for a in parsed.xpath("//c:Reaction", namespaces=NSMAP):
    print a.attrib['name']
```

I can access each of the two elements' `name` attributes by using the above code. However, when I'm in one iteration of the `<Reaction>` elements, how could I then access subelements and list them out?

I've tried this:

```
for a in parsed.xpath("//c:Reaction", namespaces=NSMAP):
    for b in a.xpath('Constant'):
        print b.attrib['name']
```

But it doesn't work.

Here's a sample of the XML

```
</rdf:RDF>
        </MiriamAnnotation>
      </Metabolite>
    </ListOfMetabolites>
    <ListOfReactions>
      <Reaction key="Reaction_0" name="v1" reversible="false" fast="false">
        <MiriamAnnotation>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="#Reaction_0">
    <dcterms:created>
      <rdf:Description>
        <dcterms:W3CDTF>2015-06-16T22:13:07Z</dcterms:W3CDTF>
      </rdf:Description>
    </dcterms:created>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
        </MiriamAnnotation>
        <ListOfSubstrates>
          <Substrate metabolite="Metabolite_5" stoichiometry="1"/>
        </ListOfSubstrates>
        <ListOfModifiers>
          <Modifier metabolite="Metabolite_9" stoichiometry="1"/>
        </ListOfModifiers>
        <ListOfConstants>
          <Constant key="Parameter_4344" name="Kcat" value="433.724"/>
          <Constant key="Parameter_4343" name="km" value="479.617"/>
        </ListOfConstants>
        <KineticLaw function="Function_40">
          <ListOfCallParameters>
            <CallParameter functionParameter="FunctionParameter_264">
              <SourceParameter reference="Parameter_4344"/>
            </CallParameter>
            <CallParameter functionParameter="FunctionParameter_254">
              <SourceParameter reference="Metabolite_9"/>
            </CallParameter>
            <CallParameter functionParameter="FunctionParameter_258">
              <SourceParameter reference="Metabolite_5"/>
            </CallParameter>
            <CallParameter functionParameter="FunctionParameter_266">
              <SourceParameter reference="Parameter_4343"/>
            </CallParameter>
          </ListOfCallParameters>
        </KineticLaw>
      </Reaction>
      <Reaction key="Reaction_1" name="v2" reversible="false" fast="false">
        <MiriamAnnotation>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="#Reaction_1">
```

Comment: `for b in a.xpath('.//Constant'):`  ?

Comment: @splash58 No that doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @splash58 No that doesn't work either sadly.

Comment: Instead of using dropbox link please paste the relevant contents of the xml file here (not the complete xml file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your parent element in an xml has a namespace, the child are also of same namespace (unless explicitely specified in the xml element), so when you are trying to search for them using XPATH , you will have to specify namespace, for children as well.

Try the following -

```
for a in parsed.xpath("//c:Reaction", namespaces=NSMAP):
    for b in a.xpath(".//c:Constant", namespaces=NSMAP):
        print b.attrib['name']
```

Comment: Ah yes, that works. THanks. However that gives me too many answers. Id just like each constant to appear once - how would I do that?

Comment: Each constant would only appear once, there may be that many constants in the xml

Comment: No there's only about 20, that produces loads. Because there's two for loops, won't there be repeats?

Comment: No, each of the outer for loop iterates over each different reaction element, and then the inner for loop iterates over each constant element in each reaction element. So the two for loops would not lead to duplicates, but maybe there is something else in your code leading to this?

Comment: There are only 26 <Constant> tags in the whole xml, so this code *must* be creating duplicates

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82422/discussion-between-okoning-and-anand-s-kumar).